# Should non-ascii characters be removed as a part of data cleaning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I typically see the removal of non-ascii characters as part of data preprocessing for NLP tasks. Is this done just to reduce the size of the corpus that needs to be learned or is their another reason for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming as defined in the guidelines

Comment: What do you mean by 'non-ascii'? ISO-646 is an ancient and very limited character set. Modern text can use all kinds of characters that aren't in there. You might want to normalize in various ways, but simply throwing out everything since 1982 is not a good plan.

Answer (score 1):

A typical representation of a text in Natural Language Processing is bag of words that essentially corresponds to counts of words. If you don't exclude such characters from your text (as a step of data pre-processing) then the bag of words for the following sentence

```
•Hello cat. I said hello cat!
```

would be (assuming punctuation and stopword removal and turning all characters to their lowercase format):

```
{ "•hello":1, "hello": 1, "said": 1, "cat": 2}
```

Therefore, you introduce noise since both `•hello` and `hello` should map to the same feature. Don't think about it as a corpus reduction. By removing such characters you will get a more representative bag of words. Once you remove such characters, the bag of words will become more meaningful:

```
{ "hello": 2, "said": 1, "cat": 2}
```

PS: This is not always the case though as it depends on the task. For some cases, non-ascii characters removal might take some information away, but for most tasks non-ascii characters shouldn't be included in the bag of words.